# Converting a specific piece of code to work with DbContext as opposed to ObjectContext

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

In Julie Lerman's excellent book on Entity Framework she showed a simple function to automatically change the ModifiedDate column of an entity if it happened to have one.  I have added it below

```
Friend Sub FixUpModifiedDates()
    Dim entries = From ose In Me.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added Or EntityState.Modified) Where ose.Entity IsNot Nothing

    For Each entry In entries
        Dim fieldMetaData = entry.CurrentValues.DataRecordInfo.FieldMetadata
        Dim modifiedField As FieldMetadata = fieldMetaData.Where(Function(f) f.FieldType.Name = "ModifiedDate").FirstOrDefault()
        If modifiedField.FieldType IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim fieldTypeName As String = modifiedField.FieldType.TypeUsage.EdmType.Name

            If fieldTypeName = PrimitiveTypeKind.DateTime.ToString() Then
                entry.CurrentValues.SetDateTime(modifiedField.Ordinal, DateTime.Now)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I am in the process of converting a legacy model that used this to EF6.x and the dbContext.  This code as is fails, one reason being that it needs to have an Imports System.Data.Entity which it did not in the original.  However the reference to ObjectStateManager is pure ObjectContext and I'm having trouble converting that to DbContext friendly code (not least because there seem to be increasingly few reference articles or books (including Julie's own book on the subject) that explain DbContext with anything other than C# code) and a lot of the freely available code converters have trouble with db and Object context specific code.

Do any of you know how this can be translated and also explain why the difference exists?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simpler way, with `DbContext` you can just override the `SaveChanges` method which provides a nicer hook for implementing such requirements:

```
 public class FooDbContext : DbContext 
 {
     ...

     public override int SaveChanges()
     {
         // this is where you plug your custom logic
         foreach ( var entriey in this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
              .Where( e => e.State == EntityState.Added ||
                           e.State == EntityState.Modified 
                     ) )
         {
             // the inner loop from Julie's code follows here
         }



         return base.SaveChanges(); // make sure the base implementation is called
     }
 }
```

If you are not satisfied and still want the `ObjectContext`, it is there. This also answers your other question - the dbcontext uses the object context internally. And you can get it:

```
 var objectContext = ( (IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext ).ObjectContext;
```

Comment: Many thanks Wiktor.  I know the basic difference between the two, it's just some of the little niceties in syntax that escape me at present.